# React use different interface in dependent on property value

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript

I have 3 different types of items, which i have interfaces of

```
interface TypeA{
  name: string;
}

interface TypeB{
 count: number;
}

interface TypeC{
 date: Date;
}
```

This items should be rendered in a list of items (in a list all items are from the same type). Depending on the type of the item, a different method is called, which will render different layouts.

```
export const ListItem: React.FC<ListItemProps> = (props) => {
  let item = null;
  switch (props.type) {
    case "A":
      item = renderTypeA(props);
      break;
    case "B":
      item = renderTypeB(props);
      break;
    case "C":
      item = renderTypeC(props);
      break;
  }
  return item;
};
```

The method should accept just items from the desired type.

```
const renderTypeA = (props: TypeAProps) => {
  {...}
};
```

The problem is that I can't get Typescript to recognize all properties of the types and also only auto-complete the respective types.

I have also tried it with a union type "ListItemTypes",

```
type ListItemTypes = TypeA | TypeB | TypeC
export const ListItem: React.FC<ListItemTypes> = (props) => {
...
};
```

but when I then try to include the ListItem, I always get an error that properties are missing.

```
<ListItem {...item /> <--- is telling me that properties are missing
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this problem?

[Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgBUBPMJAQTgG9y4cGByQAuOACIuEioOooQYuAGcYUGgHMKAX0o06DJqxEAhPgKEjxEkzItoIAV1rjqjkACN6OvbXqM0ZnZOAGFzQWFOaxC7QQATFDpxABFEpB9yB2pVOCJqOPpg7jgAXjgACjAcMGVxIq4ASlKAPnDcpBhHKGo4AB5lMBRqZvregHoBoeadCkyIbPg8gqgiszLK6trjThMmktb%20QSJO7r7J4dXx8%20nybVmsnKXCkTD1qogaupe9g4tjrp6-UGFxeV2BNzulEizAAMsBVABJOggIrKUrbYoAHwxZmxRRCsyQAA9ILA4A94HDEcjxMh0DAAHQAMRCvSpMCRSBRImUrTemx%20bQANh04MBkei3EKhbIVAB3cVoAAWFXeNQZ0Kah0E5JQymYUgkogsOrFErKTxWIi4Gw%20ygastNHiIKAA1o7dfrJLZjabBOKuejLatbTUHSadc7UO6I2g9QaYr6-QG8BakPlnqFQ-aPYIo27Zbojh0AWauTNKBT2hmoJzUxVBdqq8oFGARakYCh0QBtCPa03Q6zSAA0EcEDmcMHEAEYAEyj03aBdwAC6sv%20pzZ8I5Et4DP3LfA7cSKG0cDGEIoQA)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your code, it's throwing errors because you're destructuring an array into your component.
In your code

```
const renderItem = () => {
  const sampleData = [
    {
      type: "A",
      count: 12,
    },
  ];
  // incorrectly destructuring sampleData here
  return <ListItem {...sampleData} />;
};
```

You should be able to achieve the expected result with this instead:

```
const renderItemA = () => {
  const sampleData = {
    type: "A" as const, // notice const assertion here
    name: "name"
  };
  return <ListItem {...sampleData} />;
};
```

Because you defined `type` as literal type, you need [const assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions) so that

> no literal types in that expression should be widened (e.g. no going from "hello" to string)

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=55&ssc=1&pln=48&pc=1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgIilQ3wG4Aoc4AOxiSk3STgBUBPMJAQTgG9y4cGByQAuAlzIC41FCDFwAzjCg0A5hQC%20lGnQZNWIgEJ9pwzuPxGpgtBACutcdXsgARvS07a9RmmbsnADCpoLmCvhBNnAAJih04gAi8Uhe5HbUynBE1DH0gdxwALxwABRgOGCK4gVcAJTFAHyh2Ugw9lDUcAA8imAo1I213QD0fQONWhTpEJnwOXlQBSYl5ZXVhpxGDUXN-IJE7Z0944PLo6eT5JrTGVkL%20SIhqxUQVTVPO3vShx1dvf0zk8LoCrjdKOE4AAZYDKACSdBABUUxU2hQAPmiTJiCkFpkgAB6QWBwO7wGHwxHiZDoGAAOgAYkFuhSYAikEiRIpmi91l8WgAbNpwYCI1EuAUCiiCRQAd1FaAAFmVXlU6eEGvtBKSUIpmPhJKJpNqRWKSg8liIuGs3oo6tKTXA3EQUABrB22XX66xGx2mjmoi3LG1Ve3G7XO1Du8NoL0EKK%20x2igPmpC5R7BEN2j0Rl3RwTaA5tP7%20kBTShk1rpqDskA8Vb8rWVxRyMBC5IwFCorVhESWSRwXWk2bKAA04dk8ksk6Q%20Gk4KLR3%20rNrfDp65b4Hb8RQmjgIzBtxH8zTi1rKzKjekzdb2873fD4Us1kHKLJ45NdkcMHEAEYAEzzg6vzHCysJsmKvDrnSm5tkgHa7vuh4VseVZnoizyXk0LQ3lu8E7g%20JpPvG%20CvsOcwftqcQJDISCynAHZIKUdRAT8xagSukHQbBd6IQeUxAA)

Comment: thx a lot, the const assignment did the trick

Answer (score 0):

Here is a minimal example of discriminated union usage:

```
interface TypeA {
  type: "A";
  name: string;
}

interface TypeB {
  type:"B";
  count: number;
}

export const ListItem = (props: TypeA | TypeB) => {
  let item = null;
  switch (props.type) {
    case "A":
      item = renderTypeA(props); // TS know this must be TypeA in this block
      break;
    case "B":
      item = renderTypeB(props);
      break;
  }
  return item;
};

const renderTypeA = (props: TypeA) => {
  props.name; // No error
};

const renderTypeB = (props: TypeB) => {
  props.name; // Error
};

// Update:
const renderItem = () => {
  const sampleData: Array<ListItemTypes> = [
    {
      type: "A",
      count: 12, // This doesn't follow your ListItemTypes shape
    },
  ];
  // ListItem requires an object, not a list of objects
  return sampleData.map(sd => <ListItem {...sd} />);
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but how can i use ListItem? The problem is when i try to use it like that typescript tells me always that propertys are missing => <ListItem {...sampleData} /> "Type [...] is missing the following properties from type 'TypeB': type, count"